# NGRX effect does not see the full state as it is in the store

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have a form that is divided in several sub-forms, each has its own submit button that dispatches an action, that calls my reducer.
My the formdata in the store looks like this (example)

```
myData {
   propA1?: string,
   propA2?: string,
   propB1?: string,
   propB1?: string,
}
```

and my reducer looks like this

```
const myDataReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(FormActions.setData, (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    ...action.data,
  }))
);
```

Both forms dispatch an action

```
this.dispatch(FormActions.setData({ data}));
```

And in my devtools I see the data in the store. So far so good.
The next thing I want to do is create an effect that also listens to FormActions.setData so I can call an api when the formdata is complete. I created this effect:

```
readonly getCalculation$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(FormActions.setData),
      withLatestFrom(this.store.select(formSelector.getData)),
      switchMap(([{ data}]) => {
        console.log(data);  // this logs only partial data
        return this.service.getCalculation(data).pipe(
          map((response) => calculationActions.getCalculationSuccess({ response: response })),
          catchError((error) => {
            console.warn('error in getcalculation', error);
            return EMPTY;
          })
        );
      })
    )
  );
```

What I wanted to achieve is that this effect calls my calculation service with the full data. But when subform A is submitted the data in the effect only has 'A' properties, and the same for subform B.

I expected that **.withLatestFrom(this.store...)** I would get the complete data. I see the complete data in the store in my devtools, but somehow my effect does not have see all properties.

I use Angular9 with NgRx 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `myData` is the data that exists on the action.
You have to pick the second item in the array, that's the result of the selector.

```
ofType(FormActions.setData),
withLatestFrom(this.store.select(formSelector.getData)),
//          skip the action
//              pluck the data from selector result
switchMap(([_, data])
```